# Change the attribute value of an XML Node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

I am trying to change an existing attribute value of an XML Node that has child nodes.  I am getting an exception when trying to do this.

```
string specificOwnerPath = "Owners/Owner[@id='" + startingOwnerName + startingOwnerZipCode + "']";
XmlNode ownerID = doc.SelectSingleNode(specificOwnerPath);
ownerID.Attributes["id"].Value = ownerNameTextBox.Text + ownerZipCodeTextBox.Text;
```

The exception I am getting says 'Object reference not set to the instance of an object and is occurring at the final line of code shown above.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check

```
if (ownerID != null)
```

to before the last line. Most probably your XPath is not correct (or there simply isn't any matching element).

Answer (score -1):

if (ownerID != null)

Xpath is not correct in last line

Comment: It is not useful to duplicate existing answers. Please only post an answer if you something new to add and can provide a detailed explanation of what that is and how it will specifically answer the question.